# System doesn't load after installing DEEPIN desktop environment

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, deepin-desktop-environment

I just installed DEEPIN desktop environment using
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable`
 `sudo apt install ubuntudde-dev`

And just made sure I'm on lightdm
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

And I just powered off the laptop, now I'm turning it on and it stucks on the page loading ubuntu

Comment: Where is it getting stuck, before or after you enter your password to login to the system?

Comment: hey @KGIII ,that day I uninstalled it and everything fixed, when It was installed, and my laptop was unplugged, it wouldn't reach the login screen, but when the charger was plugged it reached the login screen(It had charge), and then(when I reached the login screen), I was using lightdm, and I could enter Deepin but gnome wouldn't open `unsupported number of argument (5); falling back to default session` , when I changed it to gdm3, both had opened successfully but still the first problem ...
I just wanted to install it again now, any tips or should or shouldn'ts that may prevent the problem?

Comment: sorry because it's getting a bit long, just wanted to Install pantheon too, any other tips on that?

Comment: My recommendation is trying the alternative desktops by finding a distro that defaults to them. That's the most stable way to do so. A Linux DE is a complicated affair and mixing and matching them can work, but often leads to instability and broken systems. For example, check the number of packages and the sizes of the packages when you go to install a new desktop.